# SQL How to loop through a table and merge result?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to do something like this:

```
while @nrOfAuthlevels >= @myAuthLevel
begin
    set @myAuthLevel = @myAuthLevel + 1 
    SELECT      Role.name, Role.authorityLevel
    FROM        [dbo].[Role]
    ORDER BY Role.authorityLevel
end
```

The result of this stored procedure shall be a table with all Role.authorityLevel below my own. But this generates several tables.

Comment: You can't think of sql as a procedural language.  You don't tell Sql how to get what you want (do A then B and return C), you tell it what you want to get (I'd like records that are like this but not like that)

Comment: Looping in SQL shows that you are not thinking in sets, and SQL is about thinking in sets (which is roughly what Will said too).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep that current structure, then you would need to insert into a temporary table for every step through the while loop, and outside of that return from the TEMP table.

That said, why not just use a **WHERE** clause to get the expected return results:

```
SELECT Role.Name, Role.AuthorityLevel
    FROM dbo.Role
    WHERE Role.AuthorityLevel < @MyAuthLevel
    ORDER BY Role.AuthorityLevel
```

Comment: You are right, I thought that there is something more in it, because the original selection anyway missed the where clause. I watched it as an example or pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temp table before the loop and don't select data, but insert data to this temp table:

```
create table #tmp (
 Name type,
 authorityLevel type
)

while @nrOfAuthlevels >= @myAuthLevel
begin
        set @myAuthLevel = @myAuthLevel + 1     
        insert into #tmp values(
            SELECT          Role.name, Role.authorityLevel
            FROM        [dbo].[Role]
            where ...
        )
end
```